# HL7 FHIR how to return data on successful as OperationOutcome

Tags: hl7-fhir

HL7 FHIR has its shape for success/error response
https://www.hl7.org/fhir/r5/operationoutcome.html Correct me if I wrong

I want to return a successful response with some data like accessToken, refreshToken  ... etc.
how can put these data in OperationOutcome shape?

### Edit

We're trying to create simple endpoints to authenticate our user (login, sign up, verify account, etc…) endpoints

the login endpoint returns an access token and refresh token for example, so how I can send these data in a standard shape of FHIR

Comment: why would you want to do that? Successful response to what?

Answer (score 0):

After searching and asking the questions on https://chat.fhir.org/

I will quote all the conversations here:

Ahmed El-Tabarani, 3:26 PM

> We're trying to create simple endpoints to authenticate our user (login, sign up, verify account, etc…) endpoints
> the login endpoint returns an access token and refresh token for example, so how I can send these data in a standard shape of FHIR

John Moehrke, 4:03 PM

> what you are describing is a normal OAuth exhange. That has nothing to do with FHIR resources.

Ahmed El-Tabarani, 4:04 PM

> So can i send the data with any format to my frontend

John Moehrke, 4:05 PM

> You MUST follow the OAuth standard during the OAuth standard exchanges
> Even if you are not using the SMART-App-Launch profile of Oauth, you will find that there is some really helpful instructions, demonstations, and sandboxes on https://docs.smarthealthit.org/

Ahmed El-Tabarani, 4:09 PM

> Ok thanks, one last question, we didn't use OAuth in our app is that opposes the standard of fhir? is it required, and should we use it ?

Grahame Grieve, 4:11 PM

> it is not required; you can use your own approach and make all sorts of mistakes that you won't be able to see but will leave your application insecure. Or you can use a very well designed and well understood specification and not make those mistakes

John Moehrke, 4:11 PM

> I am the HL7 security workgroup co-chair... I can't say it more strongly... DO NOT INVENT YOUR OWN SECURITY. Please use standards based security. OAuth is the right standard to secure clients/users to a http/restful server, TLS is the right standard to secure the communications and server identity.
> https://hl7.org/fhir/secpriv-module.html

Ahmed El-Tabarani, 4:14 PM

> Ok thanks you alot